# Чтение json ответа в Python

Tags: python, json

Отравляю в PAPI генерируемый запрос.
Получаю ответ в виде JSON данных

```
id_list_sql =

  {
  "status": "ok",
  "meta": {
    "count": 100
  },
  "data": {
    "56320": {
      "global_rating": 4602,
      "clan_id": null,
      "nickname": "Zoltan",
      "account_id": 56320
    },
    "17925": {
      "global_rating": 10649,
      "clan_id": null,
      "nickname": "Dessa",
      "account_id": 17925
    }
  }
}





       
response = requests.get(id_list_sql) #открываю ответ
data = response.json()
       
for item in data['data']:
    global_rating = item['global_rating'] 
    clan_id123 = item['clan_id']
    nickname = item['nickname']
```

Ранее я пользовался этой структурой и она работала, а сейчас вылазит ошибка с которой я на долго встрял

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
global_rating = item['global_rating']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Прошу объяснить новичку, почему лыжи не едут и как сделать что бы поехали.

Comment: А что вы сделали когда получили ошибку? Вывели содержимое `item` чтобы увидеть что там перед тем как ошибка произошла или сразу написали вопрос сюда? :) А так, по-моему, у вас в item находится не словарь, а строка. PS. смущает,  что у вас там не ссылка а словарь в `get`: `response = requests.get(id_list_sql)`, но это я так понимаю неудачно спрятали url

Comment: Скажем так, учу пайтон около недели в форсированном режиме путём написания требующейся программы. В item выдаёт 56320 и 17925. В data полный json ответ. Перед тем как сюда написать, потратил часа 4 на поиски решения. URL составляется и клеится с ответа sql запроса перед этим на 100 игроков

Comment: Сделай первой строкой тела цикла print(type(item)) а следующей print(item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, в `data['data']` у вас словарь, а при итерации словаря он возвращает ключи, а именно `"56320"` и `"17925"`. У вас же в цикле обработка идет так, как-будто там словари, поэтому и возникает ошибка при обращении к строкам.

Вы писали, что код ранее работал, получается, раньше в `"data"` возвращался список (`"data": [{"global_rating": 4602, ...`), а теперь там словарь.

Поэтому, как вариант, вы можете сразу список значений словаря запросить через `values` (а если нужен и ключ, и значение словаря, то вместо `values` используйте `items`):

```
data = response.json()
       
for item in data['data'].values():
    global_rating = item['global_rating'] 
    clan_id123 = item['clan_id']
    nickname = item['nickname']
```

---

**PS.**

Без `values` у вас было бы так:

```
for k in data['data']:
    item = data['data'][k]
    global_rating = item['global_rating'] 
    clan_id123 = item['clan_id']
    nickname = item['nickname']
```